# Swift FileManager isExecutableFile works from unit test, but fails when called within macOS app

Tags: swift, macos

I have a file with the unix executable bit set (`/Users/me/Documents/Projects/example.sh`).

Inside a Swift macOS app, I want to determine if the file has the executable bit set.

`FileManager.default.isExecutableFile(atPath:)` works from unit tests, but not from within a running macOS app. (I also tried `try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.isExecutableKey]).isExecutable`, with the same failure.)

Called from a unit test, it works:

```swift
final class MyTests: XCTestCase {
    // -> ✅
    func test_isExecutableFile_worksFromUnitTest() {
        let path = "/Users/me/Documents/Projects/example.sh"
        XCTAssertTrue(FileManager.default.isExecutableFile(atPath: path))
    }
}
```

Called within the app when running, it does not work.

```swift
class MyClass {
    // -> prints 
    func methodInAClassInMyMacOSApp() {
        let path = "/Users/me/Documents/Projects/example.sh"
        let isExec = FileManager.default.isExecutableFile(atPath: path)
        print(isExec ? "✅" : "")
    }
}
```

I’m guessing there’s some app security sandboxing in play that doesn’t come up for unit test runs?

I just want to check if a file is flagged as executable. I don’t need to actually execute it. How can I do this using Swift on macOS (13 or later)?

Comment: Sandboxed app can't access arbitrary files outside of their container. The "Open" dialogue grants access, but it basically has to be initiated by the user.

Comment: @Alexander Okay. But how do I then get permission from the user to access arbitrary files? The app I’m working on is for security checking files, and needs to be able to be pointed at an arbitrary directory and scan all the files in that directory for security issues.

Answer (score 1):

A sandboxed app can not access arbitrary files in your file system. Files have to be user-selected.
You could consider the following options:

1. Remove Sandbox from Xcode Target Signing & Capabilities tab. Remember that a not sandboxed app won’t pass in AppStore.
2. In your app, present an `NSOpenPanel` and let the user choose a file that you can then access.

Comment: Is there no way to have the user give blanket permission for accessing files? Or at least files in a given directory (e.g., Downloads, Documents, etc.)? I ran into the problem I’m having when the user selects a directory/folder in an Open dialog and I then try to check files inside that directory that the user selected.

Comment: For "Downloads" use the   Managed file access options in Sandbox settings.